# Not able to call Web API registered on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I have created a Web API which returns the list of a simple type Product. 
The controller is:

```
    Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Rice", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Dress", Category = "Clothes", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }
```

The API is working when I call from a page in same solution, referring the web api as 'api/products'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var uri = 'api/products';
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $.getJSON(uri)
     .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
                });
            });
    });
```

But the same is not working when I register the API at IIS server with url 'http://localhost:8290/api/products' and calling the API with similar ajax call in a client application.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var uri = "http://localhost:8290/api/products";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(uri)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                    $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
                });
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                $('#product').text('Error: ' + err);
            });
    });
```

Other restful APIs are working fine in similar fashion. I am not sure what I am missing here.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in the url

```
var uri = "http://localhost:8290/api/products";
```

Hosting in IIS, so virtual directory name in the url is missing. It should be something like:

```
var uri = "http://localhost/YourVirtualDirectory/api/products";
```

Comment: Yes, otherwise the same API is working when I call from page inside solution. However I checked the URL 'http://localhost:8290/api/products' at browser and it displays the list.

Comment: I've tested, it works with this url, please verify the application pool, virtual directory and access your WebAPI through fiddler: